# WordCount job is running on 'localjobrunner' instead of 'yarn'

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, local, hadoop-yarn, word-count

I am running WordCount example in eclipse luna 3.8. My job is running fine on localjobrunner but I want it to run on yarn cluster because want to access hadoop logs. Somewhere I read that if job is running on local then it do not create logs until it submit to the resource manager. Submitting job to resource manager is possible only when job is running on yarn.

My working environment:

hadoop-2.6.0 running as pseudo distribute mode.

eclipse luna 3.8.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What hadoop logs you want to access? Nodemanager and resourcemanager logs? If you are talking about your application logs then they (mapper and reducer logs) should be available on console when you run it from eclipse. About running it on YARN instead Local mode please check my answer.

Comment: Actually I have alter the coding and wants to check whether my changes reflects or not. For that I need logs of nodemanager.

Comment: Altered coding of nodemanager or WordCount example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need yarn-site.xml and core-site.xml correctly on your classpath as well as all yarn and mapreduce jars(dependencies). Now you may have those jars from maven or something but you most likely missing those config files. You can set these on classpath from "Run as configuration" in eclipse. I assume you have local hadoop installation with these configuration files and you can run hadoop commands. In that case you can point your classpath to that installation's conf dir and lib dirs. It may be tedious but start with just pointing to conf dir (which contains core-site and yarn-site) first and see if that works. If not then also exclude your eclipses local dependencies (maven or similar) of yarn and mapreduce and explicitly set them from your installation dir. check this article for setting classpath for hadoop1: 
https://letsdobigdata.wordpress.com/2013/12/07/running-hadoop-mapreduce-application-from-eclipse-kepler/

Here's another article from MapR (ignore mapr client related setup)
https://mapr.com/blog/basic-notes-on-configuring-eclipse-as-a-hadoop-development-environment-for-mapr/

You can do similar steps for hadoop2(yarn) but basic idea is your application runtime has to pickup correct jars and config files on classpath to be able to successfully deploy it on cluster.

Comment: As you mentioned.. I have local hadoop installation with these configuration files and I am able to run hadoop commands from terminal very well. But when I import these hadoop jars to eclipse then the properties which I had set in xml files(hdfs,core,mapred,yarn) do not reflect in eclipse and eclipse take default properties (like I set dfs.replication value to 1 from terminal and when I run jobs from eclipse then it shows replication value 3). I don't know how to solve it and I am using eclipse first time.

Comment: It's indicating that there are other jars/config files in your eclipse build path that are overriding jars that you intend to use. Are you using maven as a build tool and dependency management in eclipse?

Comment: Problem is solved as I was not pointing the xml file location in eclipse. Now I added the /usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop(contain all xml files) folder to eclipse and it worked..

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the Job with **YARN** specific configurations. Add these configurations in the driver,

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://localhost:8020");
conf.set("mapreduce.framework.name", "yarn");
conf.set("yarn.resourcemanager.address", "localhost:8032");
```

Comment: I have already set this property by terminal. But i am running job in eclipse and it is running on localjobrunner not on yarn framework. I hope you understand what I am trying to convey.

Comment: Where do I add these configurations?? Is it in my WordCount program?

Comment: Yes. In your Driver class.

Comment: I have added but it still running on localjobrunner not on yarn